# Citations in Beamer but bibliography in full-size portrait page

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am creating the presentation for my dissertation defense using beamer. I use several citations during the presentation which are just listed as a number in brackets. I would like the bibliography to be on a full-size page so that I can print it out and hand it to my committee members. What is the best way to do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Book1,
  author = {Noes, Hu},
  year = {2015},
  title = {Why Does LaTeX Sometimes Not Play Nice?},
}
@misc{Book2,
  author = {Nevah, p'Robley},
  year = {2015},
  title = {When will this end?},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        The solution to all my troubles is in the book by Noes~\cite{Book1}. Although Nevah~\cite{Book2} does add some useful information.
    \end{frame}

    % I want this in a Letter-sized portrait page so that I can print and handout:
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Bibliography}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with full-size page? A beamer slide without margins? Or a paper with din A4 or letter format?

Comment: I mean a paper with A4 or letter format.

Comment: check `geometry` package, not sure it works with beamer

Comment: Create an `article` mode version of your presentation which will include the bibliography and anything else you want to include there. Easiest way is to have 3 `.tex` files: almost everything in one, a `beamer` mode wrapper in the second and an `article` mode wrapper in the third. But you can do it all in one file if you insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking of using `bibexport` to get a `.bib` file with only the cited references, and create a minimal file with essentially just with the title and such parafernalia only and a `\nocite{*}`...

Comment: I'm using `biber` so `bibexport` does not work for me. However, I am using `biber document-base-name.bcf --output_format=bibtex` to get an extracted `.bib` file.

Comment: I am now using this method because the method from @cfr didn't work for a more complicated `.tex` file.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a couple of wrappers and Beamer's article-creation facilities.

For example, create `main-bit.tex` with almost everything:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        The solution to all my troubles is in the book by Noes~\cite{Book1}. Although Nevah~\cite{Book2} does add some useful information.
    \end{frame}

    % I want this in a Letter-sized portrait page so that I can print and handout:
        \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now, your main slides are produced with the following:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{main-bit}
```

[image: slides without references]

Then to produce the article version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\input{main-bit}
```

[image: references on regular stock]